# Make the matrix zero

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

Two matrices with `N` rows and `M` columns are given. Let `P[i][j]` and `A[i][j]` be the `jth` element of the `ith` row of the first and second matrices respectively. Now we want to make each element of second matrix zero. In each turn we have to choose five integers:

```
1 ≤ x1 ≤ x2 ≤ N
1 ≤ y1 ≤ y2 ≤ M
0 ≤ k ≤ 10000
```

and after this, for all pairs `(i,j)` such that:

```
x1 ≤ i ≤ x2
y1 ≤ j ≤ y2
```

The following operation is done:

```
A[i][j] = (k + A[i][j]) % P[i][j]
```

Now, i want to make the `A` matrix zero in minimum moves. What would be best approach other than picking each element and incrementing it with difference of `P[i][j]-A[i][j]`.

Example : Say we have `N=2` and `M=2` and let `P` matrix be

```
1 2
2 3
```

And Let `A` Matrix be

```
0 1
1 1
```

Then here minimum moves are 2 that are :

Move 1 : Increment each value between `(1,1)` to `(2,2)` by 1

Move 2 : Increment each value between `(2,2)` by `(2,2)` by 1

This is an optimization problem and can have many answers possible so I want the answer most closed to minimum moves.

So I need to tell minimum moves along with `x1, y1, x2, y2` and `k` for each move.

Constraints are : `N` and `M` can be upto 100. All `P[i][j]` are at max upto 10 and `A[i][j]` is always then than `P[i][j]`.

Comment: Assuming unbounded matrix entries, I'm pretty sure the worst case is going to be MN moves. Best case may be substantially lower, even 1 move for certain reasonable inputs. Do you need an exact answer, or just a sufficiently near-minimal answer? And are we limited to `k` values that will fit in a machine integer, or can we use huge values?

Comment: @user2357112 i want a sufficiently near-minimal answer.Yeah k can be at max choosen 10000 as mentioned above and M and N are in memory range .You are right worst case is MN .

Comment: IMHO example in OP is incorrect: minimum moves should be 1, `(1,1)` to `(2,2)` by 5.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev yeah in best case you are right.As i mentioned it can have multiple solutions i want solution closest to minimum moves

Comment: this is from an ongoing contest http://www.codechef.com/FEB14/problems/LMATRIX2 . please ask after contest is over .

Comment: @anon has the contest already finished?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan I believe it will be finished on the 1st of March

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: yes , today :)

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: its answer is available now in the editorial